# Is it possible to create o3d.geometry.VoxelGrid directly from numpy binary array?

Tags: python, numpy, open3d

In open3D, we can create point cloud by something like this

```
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np
pcl = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
pcl.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(np.random.randn(500,3))
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcl])
```

But for binary numpy array, e.g. `voxel`, if I want to visualize the voxel, I need to convert it to point cloud and then use `o3d.geometry.VoxelGrid.create_from_point_cloud` to convert the point cloud back to the open3D VoxelGrid

```
voxel = np.zeros((32, 32, 32), np.uint8)
voxel[16, 16, 16] = 1

# normalize
pcl = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
pc = np.stack(np.where(voxel == 1)).transpose((1, 0)) / (voxel.shape[0] - 1)
pcl.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(pc)
voxel_grid = o3d.geometry.VoxelGrid.create_from_point_cloud(pcl, voxel_size=0.04)
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([voxel_grid])
```

Is there any way to create `o3d.geometry.VoxelGrid` directly from voxel like

```
### this doesn't work
voxel = np.zeros((32, 32, 32), np.uint8)
voxel[16, 16, 16] = 1

voxel_grid = o3d.geometry.VoxelGrid()
voxel_grid.voxels = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(voxel)
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([voxel_grid])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of right now, the answer looks to be a firm no, you can't.

VoxelGrid isn't actually storing the data the way you have it. The underlying datastructure is actually an `unordered_map` of 3d indices and `Voxel` objects. I would describe it as a sparse representation, and you have a dense representation of the data (which would cover the entire domain with white and black pixels). You introduce the sparseness when you do: `np.where(voxel == 1)`.
It's also missing voxel_size, origin and of course the voxel colors.

It's not impossible to add some method like `create_from_dense_array`, but there is nothing of the sort today from what I can see browsing the code.

They could also add a pybind wrapper to the `AddVoxel`/`add_voxel` method easily, but that is also currently overlooked. Even then, it would still require you to compute the sparse voxel yourself and construct the `o3d.geometry.Voxel` object(s), probably requiring some additional utility helper method like Vector3dVector but for voxels.

Currently it seems to me that the best route is to go via the `PointCloud` like you already have done.